# bash to print log with user, date, and time

Tags: bash

I am trying to print a log using `bash` that captures the some text, logged in user, date, and time and prints it to a file `analysis`.

**bash**

```
echo "analysis done by" "$USER" "on" && date +"%D"  && date +"%r" > /home/analysis
```

However, currently only the time prints to analysis and the `echo`.... user and date print to `stdout`. Why is this the case, am I doing something wrong?  Thanks.

**stdout**

```
analysis done by cmccabe on
07/12/16
```

**desired  result (analysis)**

```
analysis done by cmccabe on
07/12/16
08:31:32 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` (like `;`) is a command separator, and redirections work at *command* level, not at line level.

If you want a single redirection to apply to several commands at once, group them:

```
(echo "foo"; date +bar) > /path/to/file

{ echo "foo"; date +bar; } > /path/to/file
```

*(In this particular case, it doesn't matter whether you use `&&` or `;`.)*

Alternatively you can output a single line with everything:

```
echo "analysis done by $USER at $(date "+%D %r")" > /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `%n` to the output format string for `date` where you want a new line.

```
date +"analysis done by $USER on%n%D%n%r" > /home/analysis
```

If there's a chance that `$USER` might include `%`:

```
echo "analysis done by $USER on$(date +%n%D%n%r)" > /home/analysis
```